# how to pass values from one view to another view extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to pass values from one view to another view, Below is the code what I have tried so far but no luck,

view1.js

```
var newWindow = Ext.create( 'newView', {"clickedRule" : clickedvalue} );
    signerWindow.show();
```

newView.js

```
Ext.define('newView', {
      extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
          id : 'newWindow',
 constructor : function (clickedRule){
                 Ext.applyIf(this, clickedRule);
                    this.callParent();
               },         
    requires : ['Ext.form.Panel'],
       title : 'Title Selection'+ this.clickedRule
});
```

I am getting undefined, your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in `Ext.create`:

```
var newWindow = Ext.create( 'newView', {
    clickedRule : clickedvalue, 
    title       : 'Title Selection ' + clickedValue
});
newWindow.show();
```

and lose the `title` config on the class:

```
Ext.define('newView', {
      extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
          id : 'newWindow',
 constructor : function (clickedRule){
                 Ext.applyIf(this, clickedRule);
                    this.callParent();
               },         
    requires : ['Ext.form.Panel']
});
```

**Edit from comment:**

You will have to put it in the `initComponent` function in that case:

`this` refers to an *instance* of your window class so won't be available in the class definition (config statements) but you can access it after the class has been initialized using the `initComponent` function:

```
Ext.define('newView', {
      extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
          id : 'newWindow',
initComponent: function (){

                 var clickedRule = this.clickedRule; 

                 // title can also be defined here
                 this.title = 'Title Selection ' + clickedRule;

                 this.callParent();
               },         
    requires : ['Ext.form.Panel']
});
```

`initComponent` is the normal way of adding constructor logic to ExtJS *components*. [See this in the docs.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-initComponent)

Keep your original `create` statement:

```
var newWindow = Ext.create( 'newView', {clickedRule : clickedvalue} );
```

You can access the `clickedRule` property after the `create` statement:

```
console.log(newWindow.clickedRule);
```

Comment: Actually I need to pass more than 4 parameters to newView and have to use it in some ajax calls also.. I am putting it into title to just check the value, but my intention is to use it later.

Comment: I tried your edited answer not working did u tried it ?

Comment: @PriyankGoswami switch `constructor` for `initComponent` function and it will work fine (see above) - tested

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I am getting value in initComponent now. But can I get it out side initComponent ?

Comment: @PriyankGoswami you can access the `clickedRule` property after the `create` statement (see last line above) - not from within the config statements - just the nature of OOP (see second paragraph in the edit).

Comment: Hey I got your point, But create is written in view1.js and I want it in newview.js

Comment: @PriyankGoswami `initComponent` is all there is for instance specific logic on components AFAIK. Any logic you are trying to do for a specific instance of `newWindow` can be done within that function. In other words, instead of trying to pull `clickedRule` out of `initComponent` the more normal thing would be to do what you are trying to do with `clickedRule` from inside of the `initComponent` function.